# Where are RAM snapshots stored by libvirt?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virsh

My understanding is that when I run this command to create a snapshot of a running domain:

```
virsh snapshot-create-as myvm snapshot1
```

that not only are internal snapshots created in each disk image file, but that the RAM state is also saved somewhere.  So if I later revert to that snapshot, everything in RAM will be restored to the time of the snapshot creation.

I see the snapshots listed within the qcow2 disk images, and I see the XML file that was created to describe the snapshot and the domain configuration, but **where is the actual contents of the RAM stored?**  And is it "permanent" so if I reboot the host machine, for example, the saved RAM state of the domain will still be available if I choose to revert to that snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The qcow2 format does provide *permanent* internal storage for the virtual machine memory. When snapshotting a running qcow2-backed virtual machines, its RAM state is dumped inside the very same qcow2 file used for storage.

From the [official qcow2 page:](https://people.gnome.org/%7Emarkmc/qcow-image-format.html)

```
Each snapshot is described by a header:

  typedef struct QCowSnapshotHeader {
      /* header is 8 byte aligned */
      uint64_t l1_table_offset;

      uint32_t l1_size;
      uint16_t id_str_size;
      uint16_t name_size;

      uint32_t date_sec;
      uint32_t date_nsec;

      uint64_t vm_clock_nsec;

      uint32_t vm_state_size;
      uint32_t extra_data_size; /* for extension */
      /* extra data follows */
      /* id_str follows */
      /* name follows  */
  } QCowSnapshotHeader;
```

which further explains:

> `vm_state_size` gives the size of the virtual machine state which was
> saved as part of this snapshot. The state is saved to the location of
> the original L1 table, directly after the image header.

---

On the other hand, what does happen when taking a snapshot of a raw image file (ie: not using qcow2)? Libvirt calls these kind of snapshot an *external snapshot* (compare it to the *internal snapshot* of a qcow2 file), because a new qcow2 file is generated and linked to the original (and now read-only) raw file. Libvirt then saves the virtual machine state (ie: its RAM content) in a specific file, generally inside a subdir of `/var/lib/libvirt/`. A metadata XML files is finally created to "glue" the dump file to the disk state saved in the overlay file.

Libvirt support for external snapshot is not very robust; for example (if things have  not changed very recently) you can create an external snapshot with a single command but you need multiple complex command to delete/revert it. At the same time, for production workload RedHat officially recommend using external snapshots because they are somewhat more robust and faster than a long chain of internal snapshots (and they sell RHEV which hides the complexity of external snapshots away from the user).